# I want to print the data as a list when the QR Code is scanned

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native, mobile, qr-code

There will be a special qr code and there will be sequential information in this qr code.Can I print the information in the incoming qr code on the bottom line when it sees a space or a symbol(@)?

https://www.hizliresim.com/qc4feyi ----- Screen output is undesirable

https://www.hizliresim.com/rkajsoy ----- Desired

https://www.hizliresim.com/lnd387j ----- Processes and permissions when scanned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\n` for new line

```js
alert("Color@100@42@1$".replace(/@/g, "@\n"))
```

After edit

```js
const text = "Color@100@42@1$".replace(/@/g, "@<br />");

document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="text" />
```

After edit : added labels

```js
const data = '@Red@Pros@42@1$'.split('@');
const labels = ['Color', 'Shape', 'Weight', 'Price'];
let text = data.map((item, i) => (item ? `${labels[i]}:${item}` : item));
text = text.join('<br />');

document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="text" />
```

Comment: Yes this code worked. Thank you.
What does the "g" in the code mean?

Comment: The " g " flag indicates that the regular expression should be tested against all possible matches in a string

Comment: I want to print the information in the qr on a new page, not the alert screen. How can I get it?

Comment: @SametCanYılmaz please check After edit code

Comment: @SametCanYılmaz please replace it with `<br />` for HTML and `\n` for JS

Comment: I want to add a title in front of these lists. I'm trying, but it always adds it to the top of all lists. My code is as below.

Comment: const ilkbilgi = 'INFO1';
  const ikincibilgi = 'INFO2'
  const filter = data.replace(/@/g, ` \n ${ikincibilgi}  \n ${ilkbilgi} ` );

Comment: @SametCanYılmaz what is data ?

Comment: My information from data qr code

Comment: @SametCanYılmaz please share data from qr code

Comment: https://www.hizliresim.com/8paw2ts ---- The data in the QR Code is like this -----@Red@Pros@42@1$

Comment: okay and what result you want ?

Comment: I want to write one comment per each line listed. Example output
Color:Red
Shape:Pros
Weight:42
Price: $1

Comment: okay give me few min. please

Comment: data = @Red@Pros@42@1$ and how is labels ? like labels will be in string or array ?
can you please provide

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question.

Comment: Are you asking if the explanations will change? (sorry i'm new)

Comment: no like what is data formate of labels, labels are Color, Shape etc..

Comment: No they said it as an example. Explanations may vary. (I hope I have answered the question.)

Comment: okay working on it

Comment: Is it silly to do it with array even though the descriptions don't change?

Comment: added new please check `After edit : added labels`

Comment: But I am working on react-native mobile programming. Is it okay?

Comment: yes this is JS + ES6 it will work just changes code of normal HTMl to JSX

Comment: you know right ? how to use this code in React ?

Comment: I guess I can't run

Comment: just take logic from above >>
and add to React >> 
like first 4 line add inside useEffect >>
and set text in useState >> 
now render that useState inside your JSX >>

Comment: now easy right ?

Comment: I guess it's easy but I'm a bit new to it. I'll try to create it according to what you said. Thank you for your time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72880307/writing-in-front-of-the-information-listed-in-the-react-native-qr-code    I have created a special question area for this, you can answer it there if you want. If it will help you if I approve your code